# Locking/Unlocking a file remotely in Subversion

Tags: ios, svn, version-control

I have Subversion setup on a Windows machine for iOS development. The WIndows machine acts as the server and all the team members are working on Macs.

I use TortoiseSVN as the SVN client and I know you can lock files using that but you have to have access to the directory in the server to do that all the time. Therefore I'm looking for a way to do it remotely.

To explain further, when a team member starts editing a file, he should be able to issue a command through the terminal (I read that you cannot do this through Xcode though a feature like that would have been great!) to lock the file and again unlock it the same way.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: "I use TortoiseSVN as the SVN client and I know you can lock files using that but you have to have access to the directory in the server to do that all the time. Therefore I'm looking for a way to do it remotely." - This makes no sense to me. If you have rights to commit to a path, you have the rights required to lock a file in that path. No special access, nor "directory access in the server" (whatever that means) is required.

Comment: anyone can unlock the file so it's kind of silly to lock it.

Answer (score 0):

`svn lock <filename>` on a file kept in a working copy is the equivalent of Tortoise's "Get Lock"